# Python / opencv: Make pixels of images be the average of nearest 4 pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I need to reduce the actual resolution of a picture so that each pixel in 4-pixel rectangle is the mean value of those 4 pixels.

i.e.

```
p1 p2 p6 p7         a1 a1 a2 a2 
p3 p4 p8 p9  ... -> a1 a1 a2 a2 where a1 = average(p1, p2, p3, p4), a2 = average(p6, p7, p8, p9) etc
```

Is it possible to efficiently do that using python/opencv not manipulating individual pixels? Does bilinear/nearest neighbor rescaling down and back to the original resolution produce the requested result(not just the visual effect)? The pictures are monochrome.

Comment: Yes. You can either use bilinear resize or a convolution.

Comment: Convolution might not work as it will operate also on samples: p2, p6, p4 and p8. I guess down and upscaling should do the trick. I would suggest upscaling manually, as there might be some filtering/smoothing included. Do something like that: create four images, where you will place downscaled samples in different locations and then just add them. Something like Bayer pattern. I hope you get what I am trying to show.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. However, are you sure that bilinear downscaling does simple averaging in that case? I would prefer to solve the task using more transparent numpy math and indexing operations, but I can't invent proper operations sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in transparent numpy/indexing based solution try something like that:

I use some dummy data to test the solution:

```
img = np.array([range(0,4), range(4, 8), range(8, 12), range(12, 16)])
```

This gives us following 'image':

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
```

Then I create four subimages by taking every second element:

```
subimg1 = img[::2, ::2]
subimg2 = img[1::2, ::2]
subimg3 = img[::2, 1::2]
subimg4 = img[1::2, 1::2]
```

Now you can average the corresponding samples using numpy:

```
average = np.average([subimg1, subimg2, subimg3, subimg4], 0)
```

And create the output:

```
output = np.zeros(img.shape)
output[::2, ::2] = average
output[1::2, ::2] = average
output[::2, 1::2] = average
output[1::2, 1::2] = average
```

And the output for given test data is:

```
[[  2.5   2.5   4.5   4.5]
 [  2.5   2.5   4.5   4.5]
 [ 10.5  10.5  12.5  12.5]
 [ 10.5  10.5  12.5  12.5]]
```

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. It is a transparent and elegant solution.

Comment: Just to make things clear: I assume your image width and height are even numbers. If this is not the case, then subimg will have different sizes.